# VBA : data validation on ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

To validate the data in my ComboBox I must click 2 times on the selected row. Do you know please how to validate the data by only clicking 1 time ?

Thank you very much !

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "data validation" in this context? How do you have a **selected row** in a combo box? Are you sure that you are talking about a combo box? If yes, is it a sheet combo box, or a form one? If a sheet type, is it a Form, or ActiveX type?

Comment: @FaneDuru it's  ActiveX type, "data validtion" : clicking on the row from list.

Comment: @FaneDuru When I clik one time I have a blue color, I must click again for validate the data row.I added the picture to my main message.

Comment: Do you know what "data validation" means? It looks you don't... What you see is the normal combo box behavior. When click an option, this is selected in the combo box, in a way you can delete/copy it. Clicking the second time, in the box or outside it, the selection is lost. What do you imagine that "data validation" should be in  this context? The combo value has been changed after the first click.